# Pandas, time series: count number of (ids, value) after running timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

Given the following DataFrame (time series table in [tidy](https://plotly.com/python/px-arguments/) format):

```
|     date     |  id  |   value   |
|--------------|------|-----------|
|  2019-01-01  |  AAA |   10      |
|  2019-01-01  |  BBB |   20      |
|  2019-01-01  |  CCC |   30      |
|  2019-01-02  |  AAA |   11      |
|  2019-01-02  |  CCC |   31      |
|  2019-01-03  |  BBB |   22      |
```

I would like to return a table indexed by the `date` column, with columns:

- `n_id` which represents the running number of `id` which report at least 1 value on a date equal or posterior to the index date
- `n_value` which represents the running number of non-null `value` which are reported on or after the index date

With the example above, the desired result would be

```
|     date     |  n_id|   n_value |
|--------------|------|-----------|
|  2019-01-01  |  3   |    6      | # ("AAA" reports [10,11], "BBB" reports [20, 22], "CCC" reports [30, 31])
|  2019-01-02  |  3   |    3      | # ("AAA" reports [11], "BBB" reports [22], "CCC" reports [31])
|  2019-01-03  |  1   |    1      | # ("BBB" reports [22])
```

What is the most optimal pandas-esque way of doing so?

Answer (score 0):

With some trial-and- error, this is my approach:

```
s = df.pivot('date','id','value').iloc[::-1].notnull().cumsum()
ret_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'n_id': s.gt(0).sum(1),
    'n_value': s.sum(1)
}).sort_index().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
        date  n_id  n_value
0 2019-01-01     3        6
1 2019-01-02     3        3
2 2019-01-03     1        1
```